# Takes more time between two dates in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

While running the following query in postgresql

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions.transactions_view 
where gl_account_id=246
```

it takes only 150 msec

But

```
SELECT * 
FROM transactions.transactions_view 
WHERE gl_account_id=246 AND tran_date between '2018-05-01' AND '2018-05-24'
```

It takes more than 9 minutes. What is the problem?

Comment: `INDEX SEEK` vs `TABLE/INDEX SCAN`. Please post table and index structure.

Comment: Check the Query plan, see at which step it's suspected to take more time and then make necessary changes.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes)  and the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: Which Postgres version exactly are you using? You initially tagged it with 9.3 **and** 9.5 - are you using both versions?

Comment: Presumably you are querying a view.  This has a big, big impact on the execution plan.  You need to include the definition of the view.  However lad2025 probably has the basic idea right:  the second is scanning tables (perhaps doing nested loop joins) the first is using the index.